# How to load a file from code instead of form field

Tags: python, django

As I don't have much experience with python and django I would like to ask about loading a file into a variable from code.

Here is my scenario:
User sends the data to my django backend with POST with some parameters like this:

```
{
templateName: exampleTemplate.html
filename: instanceFileFromTemplate.pdf
}
```

The purpose of that request is to select appropiate html template and generate output pdf file with some specific data inside. So My Django backend function selects desired *exampleTemplate.html* template and with **weasyprint** generates a *instanceFileFromTemplate.pdf* file.

Then I should prepare (programatically) a POST body/Form, where I will attach my newly generated file and save an instance into my Model

```
{
fileName: instanceFileFromTemplate.pdf,
file: -here should be a file-,
creationDate: 2020-01-07
}
```

How to do load my file into a file variable ? When I print an example body, prepared in a POSTMAN it looks like this:

```
{'filename': ['instanceFileFromTemplate.pdf'], 'creationDate': ['2020-01-07'], file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: instanceFileFromTemplate.pdf (application/pdf)>]}>
```

So basically I know i need to prepare Dict variable, but how to load into my Dist a file ?

Here below is my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import model
from accounting.models import Transaction

# Create your models here.

class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    createDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    documentTransaction = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/transactions', null=True)
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, related_name="documents", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers 
from reports.models import Document
from accounting.models import Transaction

class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    transaction = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Transaction.objects.all(), many=False, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'name',
            'createDate',
            'documentTransaction',
            'transaction'
        )
```

views.py - this is the most tricky part for me

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def documents_list(request, *args, **kwargs):
    #get parameters from body
    templateName = request.data['templateName']
    
    #Choose Template and generate PDF
    if templateName == 'tests.html':
        template_parameters = {
            "docu_date": request.data['docu_date']
        }
            
        htmlcontent = render_to_string('tests.html', template_parameters)
        with open('htmlinstances/filleddocument.html', 'w') as static_file:
            static_file.write(htmlcontent)
        #generating pdf
        pdfcontent = HTML('htmlinstances/filleddocument.html')
        pdfcontent.write_pdf('htmlinstances/filleddocument.pdf')
        os.remove('htmlinstances/filleddocument.html')
    #Load PDF into Memory and prepare 
        #how to load my file htmlinstances/filleddocument.pdf into my f variable ???
    
        BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        pdf_file_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'htmlinstances', 'filleddocument.pdf')
        pdf_file_size = os.path.getsize(pdf_file)

        docu_parameters = {
            'name' : 'filleddocument.pdf', 
            'transaction' : '265',
            'documentTransaction' : f #i expect that the pdf file should be loaded into f variable          
            'equipment' : ''
        }
        docu_body = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
        docu_body.update(docu_parameters)

        serializer = DocumentSerializer(data=docu_body)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST) """
```

Comment: You can save the path of the pdf in a model.Filefield.   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#filefield

Comment: @MichaelLindsay I'm not sure how to follow. I have added my code in the description. Can you give me a hint how to use that solution based on my code in views.py ?

Comment: does anyone could give some hint here ?

Comment: Is the goal that the `documentTransaction` has a path to the PDF? Also, is the DocumentSerializer needed in the reponse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that much of this is a work in progress...

The PDF does not need to be "loaded into memory", I am guessing that you are trying to return the path of the newly created PDF to the API for downloading.

The Document model can be created directly, and should not be created via dict -> serializer -> model create method.

After creating the model, then serialize it for API output.

I also removed the `serializer.is_valid()` because the data needs to be valid to get this far anyway.  Consider replacing that with other error handling techniques, that would include the pdf creation, etc.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def documents_list(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # get parameters from body
    templateName = request.data['templateName']

    # Choose Template and generate PDF

    if templateName == 'tests.html':
        template_parameters = {
            "docu_date": request.data['docu_date']
        }

        htmlcontent = render_to_string('tests.html', template_parameters)
        with open('htmlinstances/filleddocument.html', 'w') as static_file:
            static_file.write(htmlcontent)
        # generating pdf
        pdfcontent = HTML('htmlinstances/filleddocument.html')
        pdfcontent.write_pdf('htmlinstances/filleddocument.pdf')
        os.remove('htmlinstances/filleddocument.html')
        # Load PDF into Memory and prepare
        

        BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        pdf_file_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'htmlinstances', 'filleddocument.pdf')
        pdf_file_size = os.path.getsize(pdf_file)

        document = Document.objects.create(
            name='filleddocument.pdf',
            transaction='265',
            documentTransaction=pdf_file_path,
            equipment=''
        )

        serializer = DocumentSerializer(document)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```